# Search bar's frame in UITableview header become zero

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have a table view in first view and it has search bar. From that, I select 1 cell and it will push another view. After that, I come back to my first view and my search bar frame become zero like this. As a result, I can't see search bar but I can still tap on that. In visual debugging, I can still see search bar but on device, it disappear. May I know how it happen like this?

[image]

Comment: How did you create it storyboard/code?

Comment: I create with xib (same xib as main view)